# How to remove similar rows from a oracle table(a complex one)?

Tags: oracle, plsql, duplicates

I need to remove duplicate rows from a table i.e. the original and the duplicate one.
I have a table as below where I need to remove all duplicates records for users, 'John' and 'James' users records in below case

```
**Input Table**
| Name  | email       | N  | country|operation| 
| ----  | -----  ---  |----| -------|--------
| John  |john@abc.com | 90 | Canada | Delete | 
| John  |john@abc.com | 90 | Canada | Insert | 
| John  |john@abc.com | 50 | USA    | Insert | 
| Thomas|tom@abc.com  | 50 | USA    | Delete |
| David |dav@abc.com  | 60 | Mexico | Insert |
| James |jams@abc.com | 70 | Spain  | Delete |
| James |jams@abc.com | 70 | Spain  | Insert |
| James |jams@abc.com | 66 | UK     | Insert |
| Alex  |alex@abc.com | 65 | Denmark| Insert |

    

**Expected Output**
| name |  email       | N  | country| operation
| ----  | ------------| ---|--------| ---------|
| Thomas|tom@abc.com  | 50 | USA    | Delete
| John  |john@abc.com | 50 | USA    | Insert 
| David |dav@abc.com  | 60 | Mexico | Insert
| Alex  |alex@abc.com | 65 | Denmark| Insert
| James |jams@abc.com | 66 | UK     | Insert
```

Comment: What is the condition for delete? It is unclear - from  your expected output there is nothing complex to do here - just delete John and James who are not from USA or UK, but I think there is something else that tells which rows you want to delete...

Comment: The expectation is to delete duplicate rows(all duplicate rows including original one) based on columns Name,email,N,country irrespective of data.

Comment: The complexity comes when you are grouping based to more than two columns( i.e. Name, Email,N ,Country) and trying to delete based on that. I am able to group as below but unable to find a way to delete:

select Name, Email,N ,Country from users
  group by Name, Email,N ,Country 
  having count(*) > 1

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from table
where name in (
  select name from table
  group by name
  having count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: Thank you @OldProgrammer, I have updated the original question and increased the complexity, can you please help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Withh your data as in the question:

```sql
Create table A_TBL  AS
    
            Select 'John'  "A_NAME", 'john@abc.com' "EMAIL", 90 "N", 'Canada' "COUNTRY", 'Delete' "OPERATION" From Dual Union All
            Select 'John'  "A_NAME", 'john@abc.com' "EMAIL", 90 "N", 'Canada' "COUNTRY", 'Delete' "OPERATION" From Dual Union All
            Select 'John'  "A_NAME", 'john@abc.com' "EMAIL", 50 "N", 'USA' "COUNTRY", 'Delete' "OPERATION" From Dual Union All
            Select 'Thomas'  "A_NAME", 'thomas@abc.com' "EMAIL", 50 "N", 'USA' "COUNTRY", 'Delete' "OPERATION" From Dual Union All
            Select 'David'  "A_NAME", 'david@abc.com' "EMAIL", 60 "N", 'Mexico' "COUNTRY", 'Delete' "OPERATION" From Dual Union All
            Select 'James'  "A_NAME", 'james@abc.com' "EMAIL", 70 "N", 'Spain' "COUNTRY", 'Delete' "OPERATION" From Dual Union All
            Select 'James'  "A_NAME", 'james@abc.com' "EMAIL", 70 "N", 'Spain' "COUNTRY", 'Delete' "OPERATION" From Dual Union All
            Select 'James'  "A_NAME", 'james@abc.com' "EMAIL", 66 "N", 'UK' "COUNTRY", 'Delete' "OPERATION" From Dual Union All
            Select 'Alex'  "A_NAME", 'alex@abc.com' "EMAIL", 65 "N", 'Denmark' "COUNTRY", 'Delete' "OPERATION" From Dual;
```

here is the solution:

```sql
DELETE FROM A_TBL
WHERE A_NAME || '-' || EMAIL || '-' || To_Char(N) || '-' || COUNTRY IN
    (
        SELECT 
            A_NAME || '-' || EMAIL || '-' || To_Char(N) || '-' || COUNTRY "MY_KEY"
        FROM
            (
                Select
                    t.A_NAME, t.EMAIL, t.N, t.COUNTRY, t.OPERATION,
                    Sum(1) OVER(PARTITION BY t.A_NAME || '-' || t.EMAIL || '-' || To_Char(t.N) || '-' || t.COUNTRY
                                          ORDER BY t.A_NAME || '-' || t.EMAIL || '-' || To_Char(t.N) || '-' || t.COUNTRY
                                          ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) "ORD",
                    COUNT(OPERATION) OVER(PARTITION BY t.A_NAME || '-' || t.EMAIL || '-' || To_Char(t.N) || '-' || t.COUNTRY
                                          ORDER BY t.A_NAME || '-' || t.EMAIL || '-' || To_Char(t.N) || '-' || t.COUNTRY) "CNT"
                From
                    A_TBL t
            )
        WHERE CNT > 1 AND ORD = 1
    )
```

There is a column MY_KEY created to be like an index. Besides there are two more columns - CNT with numbers of rows for that new key and ORD with ordering the duplicate keys. The rest is ease just delete from table having concatinated table values in the list of keys from the subset where CNT > 1 and ORD = 1. Hope this could help you.
The result is:

```sql
/*
4 rows deleted.
SELECT * FROM A_TBL;
A_NAME EMAIL                   N COUNTRY OPERATION
------ -------------- ---------- ------- ---------
John   john@abc.com           50 USA     Delete    
Thomas thomas@abc.com         50 USA     Delete    
David  david@abc.com          60 Mexico  Delete    
James  james@abc.com          66 UK      Delete    
Alex   alex@abc.com           65 Denmark Delete
*/
```

The OPERATION column created with all the same values, sorry. But that doesn't change anything.. Regards...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your inputs but I have found a simpler solution to delete all duplicates including the original record:

delete from table where (column1,    column2,    column3,    column4)
in (SELECT
column1,    column2,    column3,    column4
FROM
table
GROUP BY     column1,    column2,    column3,    column4
having count(*) >1)